# jquery changing class on hover

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery but cant for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want the colors of the table row to change when I hover over the text "Change it". Please help! (yes the document is referring to a saved jQuery library)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>testestsets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#changer').hover(function) {
            $('#row1').css({
                'background-color':'#000',
                'color':'#FFF'
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>ONE</td><td>TWO</td><td>THREE</td><td>FOUR</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <p id="changer">Change it</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't like downvote ! so i delete my answer, but seriously use `code jQuery(function($,undefined) {}) ` and use `code $(document.body).on({mouseover : function(e){}, mouseout : function(e) {}}, "some selector to element to bind") ` for flexibility to add your element dynamically and most of all for way way faster jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your jQuery code in a document ready call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#changer').hover(function() {
    $('#row1').css({
      'background-color': '#000',
        'color': '#FFF'
    });
  });
});
```

Also, you had a typo in the function call with your parenthesis.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bYPks/)**

Comment: Thank you! Now if I want to change the colors back to normal when not hovering, how do I do that?

Comment: @SimonCarlson - the easiest way would be to pass the `hover()` function a second function to use when mousing out. Like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bYPks/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You're binding a `.hover` callback to `#changer` before `#changer` exists in the DOM.  Either move the JavaScript to below `<p id="changer">` or wrap it on `$(document).ready(function () {})`

You can also use the CSS pseudo-class `:hover` to do what you are trying to do, which will also handle removing the classes added on hover automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#changer').hover(
        function() {
            $('#row1').css({
                'background-color':'#000',
                'color':'#FFF'
            });
        }, 
        function() {
            // what that do when they go out
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery has a bug in it. You have a `)` in the wrong place, missing `()` after function and `)` to close the hover function.

Also you will want to wrap it within  a `$(function(){ });` so that the DOM is loaded and ready prior to assigning events to DOM elements.

Change it to:

```
$(function(){
    $('#changer').hover(function(){
        $('#row1').css({
            'background-color':'#000',
            'color':'#FFF'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You are missing a document.ready and a parentheses.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#changer").hover(function(){
        $("tr").css({
            'background-color': '#000',
            'color': '#fff'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple css to do the task

```
#changer:hover { background-color: #000;color:fff; }
```

Or if you want to use jquery :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#changer').hover(
        function() {
            $('#row1').css({
                'background-color':'#000',
                'color':'#FFF'
            });
        }, 
        function() {
           $('#row1').css({
                'background-color':'#FFF',
                'color':'#000'
            });
        }
    );
});
```